# Twilio whatsapp quicky reply in sandbox

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have started to use twilio templates with quicky replies and it is working fine for production, however, for the sandbox, the quicky replies options just don't appear, do I need to configure something for them to appear?

Answer (score 1):

Quick replies are implemented via templates within Twilio. The [Twilio WhatsApp Sandbox only has a few templates for testing](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/sandbox#sandbox-templates) and these do not include your custom ones, so you cannot test your templates or quick replies with the Sandbox.

Comment: Do we have any plans to allow testing the custom ones?

Comment: The only way to test those templates that I understand right now is with a full WhatsApp number. I would recommend getting another number for testing.